# Why does my value in localstorage have speech marks?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a mysql database with the code:

```
app.get("/api/getStudentsFromClass", async(req,res) => {
    const currentClassClicked = req.query.currentClassClicked

    connection.query(
        "SELECT * FROM ?",
        [currentClassClicked],
        (err,result) => {
            if(result){
                console.log(result)
            }
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
    )
})
```

The front end:

```
const currentClassClicked = localStorage.getItem("currentClassClicked")
    const [students, setStudents] = useState("")


    Axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/getStudentsFromClass", {
        params: {currentClassClicked}
    }).then((response) => {
        setStudents(response.data.message)
        console.log(students)
    })
```

However it says there's an error in mysql statement and shows that the statement is this

```
 sql: "SELECT * FROM '13a1'"
```

I don't know why it's '13a1' and not 13a1.
Thank you

Comment: Check in browser localstorage how is it saved?

Comment: @TusharShahi Oh when i check it's stored as a string

Answer (score 0):

Because you're telling that `13a1` is a string (as opposed to a table name):

```
"SELECT * FROM ?",
[currentClassClicked],
```

The whole point of prepared statements and bound parameters is to separate code from data.

The only way to secure your current design is to have a hard-coded list of tables, verify that received input maps a known table and build SQL dynamically, as in `"SELECT * FROM " + currentClassClicked`. But the overall idea looks strange. One would expect to find a master table with all classes and a child table with the information identified by class ID.

As per the follow-up comments, you don't create a new table for each student—there's no reason to handle classes different. However, if you want to keep your current design you'll have to hard-code tables in the application code or assume that it isn't secure and PII data could eventually be exposed.

Comment: Okay so I have a table which contains all the students details and they each have a student id. Then I have seperate tables for each class which contains the student id's of the students in that class. Is that a bad way of doing it, is there a better way?

Comment: With that design, how can you even know if a given class exist?

Comment: So initially when a teacher makes a new account, they get to enter in the classes they teach. This is put into a table which contains all the class codes and the teacherId they link to. And of course each class will always have the same students in it so I decided to store the name of the class they initially input in local storage and it can be checked if it exists and if it does it will output the data. I'm sorry if thats a little confusing!

Comment: Alright, you already have a master table with class definitions, that's good. But then, when a teacher enters e.g. 5 new classes, how do those `CREATE TABLE` statements get defined and executed? Or you update the application code when teachers need to enter new classes?

Comment: A school will most of the time have the same classes (not students in each class). So i thought I could just create all the tables for each class but now when I think about it that's quite inefficient. If the tables are all already created, the teacher just has to type in the classes they teach and it will fetch it from the database since the table would already have been created.

Comment: You can always consider it job security and call it a day xD

Comment: This is for my school project and you're right I am proabably gonna call it a day :'-D